# Space vector pulse width modulation

Tags: pwm, motor-controller, induction-motor

I have implemented space vector PWM for a three-phase induction motor.  For the further control scheme, I require to get information of active vectors(V0, V1, V2, V3, V4,....V7) getting switched in a particular sector. I have information of individual sectors and dwell times T0, T1, T2, with me.

[image]

It is like I want to plot the active vectors in real-time for each sector.

I tried comparing dwell time with a triangle wave so as to get a time vector and then writing a C function taking time vector and sector info as input to give individual vectors V1, V2.. and so on for each sector. Since the time vector is a continuous signal my C function is not able to identify the time vector as in its discrete values. Is there any other way to get the switched vectors information?

Comment: Can you use a sample & hold for that "continuous" signal?

Comment: okay I will try, Thanks for the tip